# Forum using Php

Tags: php, forum

I want to design a Forum using Php but the problem I am facing is that I dont know how can I put a Post creator in it. As far as I know something like wysiwyg editor is used for it but how can I get it. 
By Post creator I mean some thing like here on stackoverflow we are given an editor by which we post our questions. That is the same thing I need. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several great WYSIWYG editors ; to name only two of the most-used, you could think about :

- [**TinyMCE**](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
- [**CKEditor**](http://ckeditor.com/)

In each case, I suggest you read their documentation, to see how they can be integrated into your website ;-)

Generally speaking, getting the data entered by the user will not be harder than reading an element of the `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called an RTE or Rich Text Editor. There are many around.

See [here](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors)

You can also view the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700755/open-source-javascript-rte) for something similar to what stackoverflow uses.